# writing a jar file utility

Tags: java, jar

I am writing a utility jar file to be shared into multiple project. Basically it handles establishing database connection and making calculations and later return the values. Other projects will import my jar file and call my function.

Right now i am having problem when i tried to call one of the functions in the jar file.In eclipse there are no compile error but as i test it at app server i receives this error

```
22:16:35,177 DEBUG ExecutionContext:187 - Transitioning to lifecycle stage RequestComplete
22:16:35,178  WARN DefaultExceptionHandler:94 - Unhandled exception caught by the Stripes default exception handler.
net.sourceforge.stripes.exception.StripesServletException: ActionBean execution threw an exception.
    at net.sourceforge.stripes.controller.DispatcherServlet.service(DispatcherServlet.java:183)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at net.sourceforge.stripes.controller.StripesFilter.doFilter(StripesFilter.java:247)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:185)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:151)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:405)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:269)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:515)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:302)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/my/rnd/test/utils/SimplePing
    at com.app.action.JbpmProcessInstanceActionBean.testTrigger(JbpmProcessInstanceActionBean.java:83)
    at com.app.action.JbpmProcessInstanceActionBean.loadProcInstanceList(JbpmProcessInstanceActionBean.java:72)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
```

I export the jar file using eclipse and here's the sample function of the SimplePing

```
public class SimplePing {

     /**
      * @param args
      */
     public  void testSimplePing() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("This is a simple ping .");
     }

}
```

It seems that the appserver unable to find my class even to it exists in the jar file.Any help is welcomed

Comment: Do you have the jar under WEB-INF/lib when you deploy it to the app server?

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/my/rnd/test/utils/SimplePing` You are most likely missing a dependency.

Comment: How do you "import" the jar and what appserver are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look closely to the error stack you can see the following:

`Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/my/rnd/test/utils/SimplePing`

Which is a common error when you have one of the following conditions:

1. You have a `jar(s)` missing in your `lib`
2. You have some `jar(s)` missing from your `classpath`
3. You have some dependencies missing from your `MANIFEST` file:

   `...

   Main-Class: fully.qualified.MainClass

   Class-Path: lib/dependency1-X.Y.jar lib/dependency2-W.Z.jar

   ...`
4. You have a `JDK` problem

Eventually all connect to the same problem: A missing jar ( JDK or third-party related jar)
You can also use maven plugin for eclipse which will manage your dependancies of your current project and your `jar`able one which is needed by your project, ofcourse if you are fond of Maven.

Comment: May i know how can i add dependencies in my MANIFEST file? Yes the program do requires to read from another jar file. I've included the jar file in the final jar file but it still unable to find it

Comment: Do i need to specify the main class ? this is what my Manifest.mf looks like now Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.19-bin.jar lib/log4j-1.2.16.jar but it stills return error

Comment: Thanks out the 3 condition you nailed no 1 and 2. No 3 is still not working but my workaround would be adding the jar into the project (would be nicer if the manifest method works tho )

Answer (score 0):

This is a good question

There are 2 ways I can think of

1. Try to use Maven [(m2e plugin)](http://www.eclipse.org/m2e/) - this will manage the dependencies for you 
    If you do this, remember to add **Maven Dependencies** to the project **Deployment Assembly** (right click - properties)
2. Use Deployment Assembly and add the other project

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Open the jar using a program like 7-zip or winzip and verify that you see this directory structure and file in it: com/my/rnd/test/utils/SimplePing.class